# Are there Arrays and Objects in Dart?

Tags: dart

Most of what I know is Javascript. I believe "Lists" are the closest thing Dart has to Arrays, but are they technically the same thing? Is it wrong to think of them as Arrays? Similarly, would Maps be considered Objects? I realize there are likely differences, but would it be "wrong" to make that comparison?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JavaScript `Array` objects are similar to Dart growable `List` objects. Both can be added to and accessed by index. Dart lists can *only* be accessed by index, where JavaScript lists are full JavaScript objects (see below), it just has a magic `length` property that is only updated when using integer-named properties. In practice, use a Dart `List` where you would have used a JavaScript `Array`.

JavaScript `Object`s are a combination of multiple things. They are mappings from string names to values - that part is best simulated by a Dart `Map<String, Object>`. They also allow prototype based inheritance, and if you are using that, you probably want to define a Dart class instead. As a data structure, use a Dart `Map` where you would have used a JavaScript `{}` object.

Answer (score 2):

Everything is an object in Dart.
**EVERYTHING**

Comment: Not everything. For example the main()/ It's a function and not an object. Dart is not a pure object-oriented language

Answer (score 1):

Everything in Dart is an `Object` - a `List`, a `Map`, even an `int`:
https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#important-concepts

Answer (score 1):

Dart has Lists which are ordered sequences of objects. There is no class or interface called Array, though Lists act extremely similar to Arrays you might have encountered in other programming languages.

Everything in Dart is an Object.

Answer (score 0):

`List` is pretty close to JS Array.

`Map` is somewhat related to `Object` in JS, but not quite.
A map is just to store keys and values together, but in Dart you can have non-string keys. There are also no prototypes or similar for maps in Dart.